# Why server.maxHeadersCount is null?

Tags: node.js

I create simple server

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.end('okay');
});
console.log(server.maxHeadersCount) // expected is 2000, actual is null
```

[In this section of docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_maxheaderscount) It says that default value of `server.maxHeadersCount` is 2000, but actually it's null.
Any ideas why? Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: I only have two thoughts on this:
- I assume you have this initial line "var http = require('http');"
- Put "server.listen();" in the line before console.log - maybe this is needed first, but really not sure.

Comment: I think the way to interpret the docs is that the default is 2000 if server.maxHeadersCount is not set (i.e., if it's null). This property is a way to configure the server, but probably doesn't reflect the default.

Comment: @ErikReder server.listen() does not change anything.

Comment: @AkashdeepSingh It's a good point, but it's not the obvious one...